# Android force AudioRecord to use headphone mic

Tags: android, microphone, audiorecord

I use AudioRecord to record music but when I record it uses the phone mic.
how can I force him to use the channel of the Headphone?

I use this code:

```
  int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recorder[0] = false;
        }
    }, timeInSecondsToRecord * 1000);

    short[] buffer = new short[minSize];
    ar.startRecording();
        Log.d("Started","Reording");
    while (recorder[0]) {
        ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
        for (short s : buffer) {
            if (s>1000)
            System.out.println("signalVal=" + s);
        }
    }
        Log.d("Finished","Reording");
    ar.stop();
```

Thank you

Comment: did you find any real solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() for checking if the headset are plugged in or not. If the above value is false dont perform any action or whatever you want to do. And also you need permission first: MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: didn't help, when I record the record is still from the built in speaker from the phone.

Comment: @Daffa did you read the android doc file? Don't know if it will help you but here is the link [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

Comment: I already read the documentation and didn't find the solution for the problem.Even if I change the channel parameter

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in reverse (trying to force use of the phone's mic instead of the headphone mic). You can choose a mic by scanning the AudioDeviceInfo array in AudioManager. Here's what I think it would look like for you (if TYPE_LINE_ANALOG doesn't work, check out [the AudioDeviceInfo page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo) for more possibilities or debug what devices come up):

```
    AudioRecord audioRecord =
            new AudioRecord(...);
    // Force use of the line in mic
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    for ( AudioDeviceInfo device : audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)) {
        if ( device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_LINE_ANALOG) {
            audioRecord.setPreferredDevice(device);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not changing the routeDevice for me! .setPreferredDevice works well in mediarecorder but requires above 28 api